# How to show the serie of values on harmonic series?

Tags: c, math

This is about **harmonic series**. Here is an image of its definition:

[image: Harmonic series definition]

My code is giving the sum of each iteration:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  double n, sum = 0, i;

  printf("give the value of n: ");
  scanf("%lf", &n);

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum = sum + (1 / i);
  }

  printf("the sum of this series is %.2lf\n", sum);
}
```

#### But how can I show each iteration and its values?

For example:

```
1 + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4)
```

Comment: Also, never do `for (double i =...)`. You end the loop by comparing a floating point number for equality, which rarely works out well. Always control loops with integers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done adding these conditions to your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  double n, sum = 0, i;

  printf("give the value of n: ");
  scanf("%lf", &n);

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum = sum + (1 / i);
    if (i == 1)
      printf("1 + ");
    else if (i == n)
      printf("(1/%d)\n", (int)i);
    else
      printf("(1/%d) + ", (int)i);
  }

  printf("the sum of this series is %.2lf\n", sum);
}
```

With the input of: `5`, I got the following:

```
give the value of n: 5
1 + (1/2) + (1/3) + (1/4) + (1/5)
the sum of this series is 2.28
```